# Postgres optimize query on large table

Tags: query-optimization, limit, offset, postgres-9.6, bigdata

I am trying to select rows from a big table (~10M rows)
The table contains a column `timestamp` on which I set an index

I want to take rows by chunks of N rows, in order (ordered by timestamp), this is why I use `limit` and `offset`

I run parallel queries from different processes

The queries take ages, and the disk usage of my server explodes (more than 150G than normal disk usage)

Once the queries are quilled, the disk usage is back to normal

This is the explanation of my query (this one is without the `order by`)

```
my_db=# explain select * from my_table order limit 1 offset 1;
                                   QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.14..0.28 rows=1 width=1001)
   ->  Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..1447042.46 rows=10162346 width=1001)
```

Here is how the real query looks like:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM my_table
WHERE id > x
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
limit y
OFFSET z
```

Any ideas on how to optimize this process?
Lots of thanks

Comment: Select * without a where condition is never performant. It will always require a tablescan, as it obviously needs to read the full table. Especially when you add an "Order by" it will require to reorder all your 10M rows, which explains the disk usage explosion. You should add a where condition to reduce the number of results.

Comment: I actually have a row and a where condition in the query, I updated with how it looks like

Comment: You should further reduce the number of results by adding `AND ID < x + 1000` or something similar. Otherwise the number of rows it needs to sort is still a major part of the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/

This uses a unique column as a bookmark to prevent using offset